# what is $c$ in Mandelbrot set?

Tags: fractals

The Mandelbrot Set is an extremly complex object that shows new structure at **all** magnifications. It is the set of complex numbers $c$ for which the iteration indicated nearby remains bounded.
$$z_0=c$$
$$z_{n+1}=z_n^2+c$$

- what is $c$ in Mandelbrot set?
- isn't $c$ complex number

Comment: It's true, most mathematics can be subsumed into set theory. This question, however, is disjoint of any of the [set-theory] related tags on this site.

Comment: What problems do you see with $c$ being a complex number?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila
ok but there is no Mandelbrot set tag

Comment: The symbol $c$ is quantified in the definition of the Mandelbrot set: $\mathcal{M} = \{c\in \mathbb{C}\ |\ z_n(c)\mbox{ is bounded }\}$.

Comment: @Arthur Fischer i know that $c$ in short for constant but i dont know what constant, 
it could be just 1?

Comment: @Neal why you left this relation as a comment?
isnt it answer?

Comment: I can make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at an image of the Mandlbrot set it shows a region of the complex plane.  The starting ones usually run from $-2$ to $\frac 12$ on the real axis or so and from $-2i$ to $2i$ or so on the imaginary axis.  For each point in the region (at the desired grid spacing) we take the value $c$ and see if the iteration stays bounded.  We then plot at $c$ black if it does stay bounded and a color that represents how quickly it goes to infinity if it does not.  So for $c=1$ the iteration gives $1, 2, 5$ and we know if it ever gets bigger than $2$ it diverges, so we quit here and plot the color for 2 or 3 iterations.  For $c=i$ we get $i,-1+i,-i, -1+i, $ etc and it stays bounded, so we plot black.

Comment: can you proof For example, letting c = 1 gives
the sequence 0, 1, 2, 5, 26,…,
which tends to infinity. As this
sequence is unbounded, 1 is not an
element of the Mandelbrot set

Comment: @Salvador:  If an iteration is greater than 2 in absolute value, the square is greater than 4, so even adding in $c$ leaves the next value larger in absolute value.  It therefore goes to infinity.

Answer (score 7):

$c$ in the above formulas is the complex number for which you want to determine if it is or isn't in the Mandelbrot set. In images of the Mandelbrot set, the real part of $c$ is typically mapped to the $x$ axis and the imaginary part to the $y$ axis. In other words, each point of the image corresponds to a different value of $c$. Most pictures of the Mandelbrot set additionally use colours to indicate how quickly the iteration diverges for points not in the Mandelbrot set. That is, the colourful images you usually see for the Mandelbrot set are in some sense images for the *complement* of the Mandelbrot set: That's where all the structure lies. The Mandelbrot set itself, on the other hand, usually is shown in an uniform colour (most often black, sometimes white, rarely other colours).

Comment: isn't this relation better $z_{n+1}=z_n^2+z_o$?

Comment: @Salvador: As defined in the question, $z_0=c$, therefore both would be equivalent. However, another (and I think the more usual) starting point would be $z_0=0$ (which then implies $z_1=c$), and in that case $z_{n+1}=z_n^2+z_0$ would be clearly wrong. However, I don't see the advantage of using $z_0$ instead of $c$ even if starting with $z_0=c$.

Comment: i see mandelbrot set should remains bounded

Answer (score 2):

The symbol c is quantified in the definition of the Mandelbrot set: if we put $f_c(z)=z^2 + c$,
$$ \mathcal{M} = \{ c\in\mathbb{C}\ |\ f_c^n(0) \mbox{ is bounded }\}.$$
The Mandelbrot set is a subset of the complex plane, $\mathbb{C}$.  The "$c$" in the formula is just a tool to help formally express the condition for a complex number to belong to the Mandelbrot set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes $c$ is a complex number.  For the Mandelbrot set, we take a quadratic polynomial (which may be taken of the form $z^2+c$ by a linear change of variables), then investigate its properties under iteration.  There is a theorem (which Mandelbrot knew) saying that to analyze the iterative properties, we do not need to try all starting points, but can use only the critical points of the polynimial.  For the polynomial $z^2+c$, the critical point is $0$.  So we begin the iteration at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

[Map ( function) $f_c(z)=z^2 + c $](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_quadratic_polynomial) has one parameter $c$. This parameter is also a point ( complex number ) of parameter plane ( 2D plane ). On this plane there is a Mandelbrot set.

For each pixel of rectangle part of parameter plane (  [scaning](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/scanning)) one checks point $c = x + y*i$. If iteration of function $f_c$

$$ z_n = f_c^n(z0)$$

is bounded

$$ |z_n| < R $$

then point belongs to Mandelbrot set.

Here

- $R$ is constant real number ( escape radius or bailut)
- $f^n$ denotes the ''n''-th iterate of the function $f$:  $f_c^n(z) = f_c^1(f_c^{n-1}(z))$ not exponentiation

Parameter c is

- constant inside each pixel $c = x + y*i$
- changing inside parameter plane ( is different for each pixel, because y or x is changing) = variable